# STM32F3DISCOVERY microcontroller (STM32F303VC) memory size

Tags: embedded, stm32

The STM32F3DISCOVERY board's data brief indicates it features:

> STM32F303VCT6 microcontroller featuring 256‑Kbyte Flash memory and 48‑Kbyte RAM in an LQFP100 package

However, the reference manual (RM0316) for STM32F303x6 et al. indicates only 16 Kbytes of SRAM (section 3.3) and 64 Kbytes of Flash memory (section 4.1) for STM32F303x6. The 256 and 48 Kbyte values match up with the STM32F303xB/C, which is also what is linked to on the board's data brief under Table 1's "Target STM32", even though it says "STM32F303VCT6".

I don't understand why there appears to be a discrepancy. Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: Please write your own answer and mark it. Or delete the question. Keeping it unsolved does not help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I did not realize x was a single-letter substitution. I thought that in STM32F303x6, x replaced VCT. It does not. STM32F303VCT6 matches to STM32F303xC (x replaces V), and the T6 is a specific product in this line of chips.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version on the st website seems right: [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00043574-stm32f303xbcde-stm32f303x68-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-armbased-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

For the STM32F303VC:

> STM32F303xB/C and STM32F358xC devices feature up to 48 Kbytes of static SRAM.

For the STM32F303x6:

> STM32F303x6/8 and STM32F328x8 devices feature the same memory but only up to 16Kbytes of static SRAM

Maybe you have a old copy with a typo?

Comment: That's what I was looking at. What am I misunderstanding then? It says "the same memory"... what does "memory" mean here? And "the same" as what? The way it is written, I would assume STM32F303xD/E.

Comment: STM32F4DISCOVERY has a STM32F303VCT6 with 48KBytes of SRAM. 
STM32F303x6/8 has only 16KB of SRAM, same memory stand for same kind of SRAM clocked in the same way in the same BUS with the same timings, I presume. Only dimension changes.